# getting indexes of different elements in the same Array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have 3 arrays example:

```
String[]arr1={"1150","3309","44","22","98","88","33","11","880"}
String[]arr2={"5","9","44","22","65","20","41","3","9","5"}
String[]arr3={"1","3","20","22","30","40","15","2","4","0"}
```

i want to get indexes for elements in the first array(arr1) that starts with `["11" , "88" , "33" ]`
and after getting them I have to multiply the elements of the other two arrays with the same indexes example:`"1150" Starts with "11"`,`"3309" starts with "33"` so i have to multiply `1*5` , `9*3` ..etc and store the in some variable which I can't imagine what data structure should I use for it.

```
 for (int k = 0; k < index - 1; k++) {
                if (arr1[k].substring(0, 2).equals("11")
                        || arr1[k].substring(0, 2).equals("88")
                        || arr1[k].substring(0, 2).equals("33"))
    {
    //don't know what should i do then
    }

    }
```

I tried this:

```
Integer x=Integer.valueOf(arr2[k])* Integer.valueOf(arr3[k]);
```

but then I figured out that k should have many values for the different occurrences of my targeted strings. so this line caused me an error.
any help would be appreciated thanks !

Comment: "11" also starts with "11" - Why is it `5*1` and not `9*4` ? Or are you supposed to do both but only provided an example for the first one?

Comment: @DarthAndroid I wrote ..etc btw which means I'm supposed to do both and I just wrote an example.

Comment: Ah, I thought the "etc" was for the example for `88` that wasn't provided; My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Since it takes two to multiply, you need to make two nested loops iterating the same array `arr1`. Since you do not want duplicates, start iterating the nested loop from the index one past that of the outer loop. The pattern looks like this:

```
for (int k = 0 ; k < arr.Length ; k++) {
    if ( /* check if k is not a good index */) {
        // If k is not an index of something we want, move on with the loop
        continue;
    }
    // Start iterating at the next position after k
    for (int m = k+1 ; m < arr.Length ; m++) {
        if (/* check if m is a good index */) {
            ... // Do something with indexes k and m
        }
    }
}
```

The only other thing you should do is making sure that your code does not break when `arr1[i]` has fewer than two characters. Currently, your code would throw an exception. A better approach is to use [`StartsWith("11")`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw(v=vs.110).aspx) method, which would not throw even for an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Your output is unclear, still some code doing something close to what you asked :

Match.java

```
public enum Match {
    // Using an enum to get flexbility
    _11("11"),
    _33("33"),
    _88("88");
    public String value;
    private Match(String value) { this.value = value; }
    // This function checks if the given string starts with one of the matches
    public static Match fromString(String s) {
        for (Match m : Match.values()) { if (s.startsWith(m.value)) return m; }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Test.java

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[]arr1={"1150","3309","44","22","98","88","33","11","880"};
        String[]arr2={"5","9","44","22","65","20","41","3","9","5"};
        String[]arr3={"1","3","20","22","30","40","15","2","4","0"};

        Map<Match, List<Integer>> indexes = new HashMap<Match, List<Integer>>();
        // First initialize the map with empty list
        for (Match m : Match.values()) {
            indexes.put(m, new ArrayList<Integer>());
        }

        // Then a loop to find the indexes in the first array of the elements starting with one of the matches.
        for (int k = 0; k < arr1.length ; k++) {
            String cur = arr1[k];
            Match m = Match.fromString(cur);
            if (m != null) {
                indexes.get(m).add(k);
            }
        }
        // Finally loop on all patterns to get the computed result (based on 2nd and 3rd array content)
        for (Match m : Match.values()) {
            System.out.println("- " + m.name());
            for (Integer i : indexes.get(m)) {
                System.out.println("  - " + i + " > " + (Integer.valueOf(arr2[i]) * Integer.valueOf(arr3[i])));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

outcome:

- _11

  - 0 > 5
  - 7 > 6
- _33

  - 1 > 27
  - 6 > 615
- _88

  - 5 > 800
  - 8 > 36

Comment: That worked for me thank you man but I need some help if you don't mind cause I never used Maps before in java. I am stuck with a little problem If I need to check on values of 11 , 33 or 88 which are in the indexes map. How could I control them ? I need to say for example  if  "11" contains any value > 10  which in that case (5,6)     System.out.println("good") btw I printed indexes and i got something like this   {_88=[5, 8], _11=[0, 7], _33=[1, 6]} but i cant loop on it or check its values

Comment: and when i tried this: ` for (int k = 0; k < indexes.size(); k++) {
   System.out.println(indexes.get(k));
  } `  and the output was 3 nulls

Comment: Hm you should read the Map javadoc ;) in my sample you have access to the map indexes with : map.get(index). Ill update my post with some comments explanation !

Comment: i think when i use map.get(index) I should get the elements in the map so why does it print 3 null ?

Comment: and why when i try system.out.println(indexes.get(0)) or system.out.println(indexes.get(1)) or system.out.println(indexes.get(2)) i get null ??

Comment: indexes key are 'Match' object, meaning you should access indexes.(Match._11) for example. Indexes is not a list, its a map of list. So you first need to iterate on the keys (Match obejcts) then on the values (List).

Comment: hey man I need your help and I can't catch you anywhere . if you can help me in that would be really appreciated [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36607917/failing-in-inserting-values-in-maps-java]

Answer (score 0):

You should store each `x` in an list structure, like `LinkedList`. You can only have one match for each value of `k`.

```
List<Integer> results = new LinkedList<>();
for(int k = 0; k < arr1.length; k++) {
    // Check if the first character is "1", "3", or "8", and that the
    // second character is the same as the first. This assumes that
    // there are no null elements and no numbers less than 10.
    if ("183".indexOf(arr1[k].charAt(0)) > 0 && arr1[k].charAt(0) == arr1[k].charAt(1)) {
        results.add(Integer.valueOf(arr2[k]) * Integer.valueOf(arr3[k]));
    }
}
// results now contains all the multiplied values.
```

Comment: thanks for being helpful. could you elaborate a bit more ?