# failing in inserting values in maps java

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to insert values into maps in java to loop on them and do some calculations so what I am doing is to read a folder of 11k files which containing somethings like these:
 ps: all the files have the same structure

```
 SFrm  EFrm   SegAScr Phone
        0    36   -158051 SIL
       37   105   -644247 +NONTRANS+
      106   109    -96452 l SIL w b
      110   112   -125055 w l aa i
      113   115   -150550 aa w 7 i
      116   118   -146662 7 aa i i
      119   122    -46757 i 7 d i
      123   126    -58440 d i SIL e
      127   146    -90776 +MUSIC+
      147   152    -61098 t SIL u b
      153   158    -67393 u t f i
      159   174   -251284 f u f i
      175   178    -79772 f f aa i
      179   194   -134562 aa f 7 i
      195   206    -33695 7 aa a i
      207   223   -194024 a 7 SIL e
      224   350   -434997 +NOISE+
      351   353    -28280 SIL
 Total score:    -2802095
```

and checking on them by the code below

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class z {
//Enum to match the vowels with string values
    public enum Match {
        _aa("aa"), _ii("ii"), _uu("uu");
        public String value;

        private Match(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public static Match fromString(String s) {
            for (Match m : Match.values()) {
                if (s.substring(4, 6).equals(m.value))
                    return m;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException,
            IOException {

        **//reading folder**
        File folderPhseg = new File(
                "/home/bassem/workspace/outputs/new");
        File[] listOfPhseg = folderPhseg.listFiles();

        Map<Match, List<Integer>> indexes = new HashMap<Match, List<Integer>>();
         for (Match m : Match.values()) {
                    indexes.put(m, new ArrayList<Integer>());
                }
        String line = "";
        for (File file : listOfPhseg) {
            if (file.isFile()) {

                FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(file.getAbsolutePath());
                BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(inputFile);
                String[] column1 = new String[100];
                String[] column2 = new String[100];
                String[] column3 = new String[100];
                String[] column4 = new String[100];
                String[] column5 = new String[100];
                int index = 0;
                  //converting it into five arrays
                while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {

                    String temp = "";
                    int count = 1;
                    column4[index] = "";
                    // System.out.println(line);
                    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");

                    // String tokenizer gets the token from each space
                    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {

                        temp = st.nextToken();
                        if (temp.equals("Total")) {
                            break;
                        }
                        // parsing input
                        if (count == 1) {
                            column1[index] = temp;
                        }
                        if (count == 2) {
                            column2[index] = temp;
                        }
                        if (count == 3) {
                            column3[index] = temp;
                        }
                        if (count == 4) {
                            column4[index] = temp;
                        }
                        if (count == 5) {
                            column5[index] += temp;
                        }

                        if (count < 5)
                            count++;
                    }

                }
                    //storing them into Maps

                for (int k = 0; k < index - 1; k++) {
                    String cur = column5[k];
                    Match m = Match.fromString(cur);
                    if (m != null) {
                        indexes.get(m).add(
                                Integer.valueOf(column3[k])
                                        - Integer.valueOf(column2[k]));
                    }
                }

                index++;

            }


        }
        System.out.println(indexes);

    }
}
```

I store these data into the map with key `Match` then when I try to print the map I get an empty one!

I tried this code on one of the files and it worked well with me.
the problem is when I try to apply it on the whole folder I get nothing in the map. After debugging the code I figured out that the last for loop isn't getting executed and this loop is the one concerned with storing in map but I can't figure out the reason behind that. I tried to move `index++;` to be above the for loops. The code Entered the mentioned for loop but at the end I got the same output

Comment: A) whats your question B) use a debugger, any question you have will boil down to you asking us to debug your code for you.

Comment: @redFIVE I pressed `Enter` by mistake while writing my question !! then I edited it

Comment: Ok, so how is my point about you debugging your own code any less valid? You still dont have a question anywhere, just statements about you can't do it

Comment: Pressing Enter in the text area doesn't save the question.

Comment: @Tom why should I lie to you or to him ?! he wrote a comment in less than a minute after submitting my question. Btw I read his comment after editing my question.

Comment: *"why should I lie to you or to him?!"* I don't know either. But pressing Enter while _writing_ also doesn't save the question. But anyway ... have you tried to use a debugger? Have you checked that `listOfPhseg` correctly contains the list of your files? If not, may try `"/home/bassem/workspace/Bachelor/outputs/new/"`.

Comment: @Tom I did check them it and yes it contains all my files

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're doing a nasty overwrite here - in each iteration you lose all the values and you start counting from zero...

```
//storing them into Maps
for (Match m : Match.values()) {
    indexes.put(m, new ArrayList<Integer>());
}
```

Also, after the last line you "break" out of the inner cycle, but the map will be overwritten with empty stuff anyway.

Move the above "for" block right after the part where you create the "indexes" map.

Comment: this loop is for creating the structure of my printed map with the 3 keys I have in the Enum When I removed it i get actually an Empty output just like this `{ }` and the code still can't enter the loop, but when i have it I have this `{_uu=[], _ii=[], _aa=[]}` which is actually what I need. The output integers should exist in their match but I get an empty one

Comment: I said you should move that block to a different part of your code, not remove it. Like this:

    `Map<Match, List<Integer>> indexes = new HashMap<Match, List<Integer>>();
    for (Match m : Match.values()) {
        indexes.put(m, new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }`

Comment: I did this but it didn't help

Comment: hey dude I am still stuck in the same problem for the second week ! can you help ?!